# Clean pending changes "ADD" in VS2010 TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there way to clean up pending changes with "Add" value in column "Change" . They seem to be related to open solution according to folder path, but not present either in the solution or file system.  Pressing "Filter by solution"  actually doesn't show them and shows "Delete" for other files in unrelated projects which is also confusing. There were manipulations to move solutions to other root folders which could contribute to that. All those solutions are not really used, so any possible undo will do :), but not clear how to purge all those dirty entries from pending changes window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just click the Change column header to sort by Change type, highlight all the Adds right-click Undo.