# Clean pending changes “ADD” in VS2010 TFS 2010 in One Click

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I know this question is asked many times on this portal.

Like this: [Clean pending changes "ADD" in VS2010 TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877239/clean-pending-changes-add-in-vs2010-tfs-2010),  [How do i remove files from the Pending Changes list in TFS when those files have been deleted locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770727/how-do-i-remove-files-from-the-pending-changes-list-in-tfs-when-those-files-have)

We have an option of undo for it. but currently it is only for single item. I have 200+ pending ADD changes file.I want to remove all of them in one click.

Is any body know the perfect solution to get rid of this problem.

Comment: why doesn't the accepted answer in the first question you link to work for you? You can highlight all of the "add" actions in the pending changes window and right click and select "undo" this will undo all of the highlighted pending changes, you do not need to do them one by one.

Comment: Dear @JamesReed, Have you tried it.It is not working when i select the all pending changes. It simply disable the UNDO button. It is Enabled for single but for Root Node it disabled.

Comment: Are you using the pending changes window or the checkin dialogue?

Comment: Both work fine for me. All I can think of is that you need to have the TFS 2010 power tools installed, this may enable the ability to select multiple files.